# Google Spreadsheet Trigger which will fire when the active selection changes for a given sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

This would be equivalent to the Excel `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event.

Comment: Welcome. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested on [ask].

Answer (score 0):

**Not possible** in Google sheets.  There is no such "*Event*" in Google sheets.

You should read about the  various Google Sheets-specific triggers that let scripts respond to a user's actions in a spreadsheet. [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_sheets_events) on GAS (Google Apps Script).

> The type of change (**EDIT, INSERT_ROW, INSERT_COLUMN, REMOVE_ROW, REMOVE_COLUMN, INSERT_GRID, REMOVE_GRID, FORMAT**, or **OTHER**).